# PostgreSQL unique index based on a ranged numeric field

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a `scheduleitem` table with columns for `room`, `dayofweek`, `starttime` and `endtime`. I'd like to be able to create a unique index on `room` and `dayofweek` where the predicate (somehow) prevents the table from containing overlapping times, that is, prevent overlap where a potential new row `r2` and any given existing row `r1` satisfy

```
r2.endtime > r1.starttime and r1.endtime > r2.starttime
```

So far I can't add a subquery to the partial index predicate, and any stored procedure that I reference in the list of unique columns has to be immutable (can't run any queries), so I'm stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the feature EXCLUSION CONSTRAINTS - see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtable.html and look at the part about EXCLUDE.

Comment: +1 for EXCLUSION CONSTRAINT. That's exactly the thing they were created for

Comment: Good answer, though it's a shame that Ubuntu is stuck with postgres 8.4 without repo hacking.

Comment: Use the Ubuntu PostgreSQL PPA: https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql -- it's ran by the PostgreSQL maintainer for Debian/Ubuntu, so it should be as stable as the official version.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a trigger? You can read about them [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/triggers.html).

Comment: How would you propose I use the trigger?

Comment: I would have preferred using an index instead of a trigger because as far as I know, indexes increase performance and triggers do the opposite.

Comment: @Reinderien: Not necessarily. A unique index is a combination of an index and a constraint, the index part makes queries faster, the constraint part makes modifications slower because the uniqueness has to be verified before the UPDATE or INSERT can complete.

Comment: Makes sense. Anyway, I succeeded in making a `before insert or update` `for each row` plpgsql trigger that does the trick.

Comment: @Reinderien - It depends. If you can use an index, that's almost always the better choice. However, nothing, and I mean absolutely nothing is more important than your data integrity, so if a trigger is needed to make sure no bad data gets into your table, then I wouldn't hesitate to use it (make sure you test performance obviously). I've worked with too many DB's where nobody cared about data integrity, and in all cases these DBs were train wrecks. I recommend the trigger.

Comment: having the trigger enforce the constraint when multiple clients are updating the table concurrently isn't trivial, though. a naive implementation will allow two clients to insert conflicting data: uniqueness and exclusion constraints have additional complexity in there to prevent this.